# How to debug edgeHub module in Azure IoT Edge

Tags: azure-iot-edge

is there anyway to trace the messaging flow in edgeHub?
i have two modules that connect sensors (the opc-ua publisher) and a coap proxy and i am routing them to the cloud with
"all2hub": "FROM /messages/* INTO $upstream"
That works fine and I can see the telemetry from both devices
If i add another module that does nothing but writes to the console every message it receives with
"all2test": "FROM /messages/* INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/tester/inputs/test\")"
I don't get a single message coming to the test module...I wonder if I could trace and see what is happening....

Answer (score 3):

You can enable debug logs for edgeHub by adding **RuntimeLogLevel** environment variable with value **debug** to the deployment (from the portal go to Set modules -> Configured advanced Edge runtime settings)

Another way to enable debug logs is by updating the IoT Edge security manager config file

Replace env: {} with

```
env:
  RuntimeLogLevel: debug
```

Save the file and restart the IoT Edge security manager.

With debug logs enavled you should check edgeHub logs if messages are received and sent.

Comment: Is this the right/only location for the logs? /var/lib/docker/containers//-json.log    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53732960/azure-iot-edge-module-log-location/55088631#55088631