# Azure IoT Edge module log location

Tags: azure-iot-edge

Where are the logs exposed by the `iotedge logs <container>` command stored?

Where would that be generally on Linux?

Answer (score 6):

Simply do a `docker inspect <Container ID>` and under `LogPath` you will get the current location of the container. E.g. for `EdgeHub` on my machine: `LogPath`:

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/f8ecdf408f94f5627ac635223ce89dd9b1433705f342d548e09863cedf0fc950/f8ecdf408f94f5627ac635223ce89dd9b1433705f342d548e09863cedf0fc950-json.log
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, they are stored in /var/lib/docker/containers//-json.log.